# dell md series device specific module for multi-path failed to return a path?

Tags: storage-area-network, dell-poweredge, fiber, dell-powervault

We have a Dell PowerVault 3620f (fiber) and I am getting the following errors in the Windows event log. I am no good with fiber zoning so I would need to pull in someone to take a look but figured I would ask here first. We also have a mirrored setup at another location with the same hardware and I am not seeing the issue. Looking at the MDSM, I don't see any issues. The SAN and server are out of support, otherwise I would call Dell.

```
Dell MD Series Device Specific Module for Multi-Path failed to return a Path to \Device\MPIODisk2.
```

Answer (score 1):

That could be a problem with the MPIO DSM itself. I'd suggest trying an uninstall of MDSM, and re-install from the latest [resource DVD](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/DriversDetails?productCode=powervault-md3620f&driverId=R9G1X) version.

If that gets you nowhere, you may need to do some digging into the logging of the switches to verify there are no problem there.

Comment: Also, make sure that you've got connectivity to all ports - you should be able to ping the storage interfaces from the Windows host.

Comment: @Zac67 well, they mentioned it’s a Fibre Channel system, so ICMP pings aren’t an option... but you’re right, need to verify all ports have links and that each one can reach its respective port on the other end.

Comment: With FC, there could also be a zoning issue on the switch/director.